Laravel metodo Update no ejecuta cambios en la base de datos
tengo 2 controladores en un proyecto de laravel en los que la funcion update no hace cambios en la base de datos. Tanto con una request PUT o PATCH o mandando el request en un query o un json en el postman, no ejecuta los cambios. No da ningun codigo de error, me retorna la vista de Index, pero ninguno de los cambios ha sido ejecutado.
Este es el codigo de las dos funciones Update
    public function update(Request $request, entrades $esd)
    {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

        try {
            $esd->update($request->all());

        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            return redirect('entrades');
        } finally {
            return redirect('api/entrades');
        }
    }

    public function update(Request $request, esdeveniments $esd)
    {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

        try {
            $esd->update($request->all());

        } catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
            return redirect('esdeveniments');
        } finally {
            return redirect('api/esdeveniments');
        }
    }

Y estas dos de las requests en el postman tras hacerlas. Como dije, me da el indice, pero no se hicieron los cambios.


EDIT: Los modelos de "esdeveniments" y "entrades", las dos tablas de este problema.
class esdeveniments extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
        'data_esdeveniment',
        'aforament',
        'limit_entrades'
    ];
    public function entrades()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(entrades::class);
    }
}

class entrades extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'nom',
        'correu',
        'data_compra',
        'esdeveniment_id'
    ];
    public function esdeveniments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(esdeveniments::class);
    }
}

Route::resource('esdeveniments', ApiEsdevenimentsController::class)->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified']);

Route::resource('entrades', ApiEntradesController::class)->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified']);


Las rutas que tengo en el archivo de rutas, y las rutas que muestra el comando php artisan route:list

Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal para que no se hagan los cambios y no de ningun mensaje de error? Entiendo que el problema es el mismo en ambas funciones.

mmm intentaste porbar por POST o GET ??? te lo pregunto por que no veo el codigo de Backend en donde Implementas que el router debe ir por PATCH o PUT... entonces en la version por defecto deberia ser por POST o GET

Son campos nuevos que ya existian? Me ha pasado que se me olvida actualizar el Modelo a veces cuando hago cambios y los campos nuevos jamas se guardan si no los agrego como fillable

No ocupas el ORM integrado de Laravel? Para hacer un update es solo crear una nueva instancia del model y ejecutar el metodo propio update de Laravel

POST y GET me funcionan sin problemas, las entradas que salen retornadas en mis imagenes las cree mediante un metodo POST.

Ya existian las dos tablas, pondre los modelos en mi pregunta de todas formas

No,estoy usando el ORM, como podria usarlo en este caso?

Saludos, muestra como declaraste la ruta en tu archivo. Creo que tu problema se da porque no se está instanciando correctamente tu modelo esdeveniments. Entonces primero valida de que $esd se esté instanciando correctamente. En segundo lugar, en vez de mandar id por el query params cámbialo a esd con su respectivo valor.

Buenas, gracias por responder, he actualizado la pregunta con las rutas tanto del archivo de rutas, como las que salen con el comando php artisan route:list.
Como podria validar que esd se esta instanciando correctamente?

dale un return response()->json($esd);. Debe retornarte el objeto instanciado.

Trata de cambiar de $esd a $entrades, de esta manera por ejemplo public function update(Request $request, entrades $entrade )

Por lo que veo tu error viene dado a como estás nombrado tus intancias de los modelos en tus diferentes métodos.
Como puedes ver en tu rutas (api/entrades/{entrade}/edit), estas esperan a que la variable sea llamada $entrade por lo que tu variable debe llamarse así en tu controlador.
public function update(Request $request, entrades $entrade)
{
    // Toda tu logica
}

Por otro lado por convención tus modelos deben ser escritos en camel case y en singular, por ende, debería estar nombrado de la siguiente manera Entrade.
Entiendo que con la corrección de la variable es más que suficiente para que tus registros puedan ser actualizados de manera correcta.

Si, esto lo soluciono, tanto el Entrades como el Esdeveniments. Muchas gracias.
